# How do I run Firefox inspector within an iFrame?

Tags: firefox, iframe, firefox-addon, firebug, firefox-developer-tools

I know Chrome's inspector has a selector to choose which frame to use with the console. Firebug has a similar command, `cd(window.frames[number])`. Is there anything similar in Firefox Devtools? I suppose frame.window.eval could work, but only if it isn't cross-domain.

I was also wondering if there is a highlighter to inspect results of Web-console commands, for example `document.getElementsByClassName(...)`. but you can at least change style of an element programmatically to 'see' it.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not just Web Console, the inspector's css style view/edit is also a broken when inspecting iframes. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=880098

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DOMNode objects do highlight in the page on hover in the web console and what is called the "variables view". The "variables view" is used in the web console too when you click on an object to see its properties (it's the sidebar that appears), and is also used in the debugger when paused at a breakpoint (right sidebar that contains the various scopes variables).

So, anytime a DOMNode appears in there, if you hover over it, it will be highlighted in the page.

When it comes to iframes, the webconsole does support the `cd()` command, see [working with iframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console#Working_with_iframes).

We are also actively [working on a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=977043) that will add a drop-down to the toolbox whenever there are frames/iframes in the current page and allow you to easily switch from one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can [click to inspect a node](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=952277) in the console and debugger [starting in Firefox 29](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/02/css-source-map-support-network-performance-analysis-more-firefox-developer-tools-episode-29/), currently on the [Aurora channel](http://www.mozilla.org/firefox/aurora/).

Comment: I saw that, in Nightly the other day - the right icon next to x. It would be nice if it highlighted on mouseover, not click.